# Terminal opens but shows an error and doesn't work properly

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

I have a MacBook with macOS Sierra (10.12.6) installed on it. Something has happened to Terminal, and I can't use it anymore. This is the message I get whenever I open Terminal.

```
Last login: Fri Oct 27 15:52:59 on ttys000
-bash: /etc/profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /etc/profile: line 1: `-e \n-e \n# System-wide .profile for sh(1)\n\nif [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then\neval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`\nfi\n\nif [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then\n[ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc\nfi\nPT7HOME=/opt/pt\nQT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=auto'
-bash-3.2$
```

Most commands don't work in this mode, and I tried to use `su - root`, but I get the same error above.

I also used the "pwd" command and it tells me that I'm in my user's home folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my issue.

I replaced every `\n` with a line break, also deleted those two `-e`s from the first line.

Answer (score 2):

Something has modified `/etc/profile` and left it with syntax errors.  You need to open it in an editor, correct the problems, and save it.  Or, find out why it's changed and undo the edits.

It looks, at a guess, as though something has added `-e` twice to the top of the file.  I don't know what would normally be in that file but a quick check online suggests it should have `# System-wide .profile for sh(1)` as the first line.

You'll need to make sure nothing else has changed accidentally.